# Send array of string to WebAPI using ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I need to send an array of strings to WebApi. I tried the following code but I didn't get the expected output.

**In Javascript:**

```
$.ajax({
    url:serviceUrl+'/sample',
    type:'POST',
    data:['a','b','c'],
    contentType:'application/json',
    dataType:'JSON'
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

**In Controller:**

```
[Route("sample")]
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(string))]
public IHttpActionResult GetSample(List<string> dataFromUI)
{
    return Ok("Success");
}
```

In WebAPI I'm getting dataFromUI with no elements.
I even tried JSON.stringify to send data but I got dataFromUI as null this time.

I will be glad if I get the answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to convert your array into an object containing the array you wish to send as a property matching the name of your action's paramter as below:

```
JSON.stringify({ dataFromUI: ['a','b','c'] })
```

The full code would look like:

```
$.ajax({
    url:serviceUrl+'/sample',
    type:'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({ dataFromUI: ['a','b','c'] }),
    contentType:'application/json',
    dataType:'JSON'
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Getting dataFromUI as null

Comment: Do you mean your controller is receiving dataFromUi as a null value?

Comment: Yeah, I'm receiving dataFromUi as a null value

Answer (score -2):

You set route 'sample' for your action , try to call with sample action

```
$.ajax({
    url:serviceUrl+'/sample' ( or your action route),
    type:'POST',
    data:['a','b','c'],
    contentType:'application/json',
    dataType:'JSON'
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```